# Regular expression for parsing Active Directory distinguishedName

Tags: regex, parsing, active-directory, distinguishedname

The value for distinguishedname in AD is typically in the format:

```
CN=lastName\,firstName,OU=Users - XYZ,OU=Users-Test Place,OU=UsersAll,DC=Dom1,DC=Dom2
```

I would like to parse it using a regular expression and get back the following values

```
CN=lastName\, firstName
OU=Users - XYZ
OU=Users-Test Place
OU=UsersAll
DC=Dom1
DC=Dom2
```

The pattern "\w+=\w+" didn't help.

I see the problem but am at a loss for a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What language / platform are you attempting this from?  I.E., regular expressions simply probably aren't the best choice for this.  Use something that is meant for parsing these names, e.g. javax.naming.Name in Java.

Comment: I'm trying to parse in PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for Distinguished Names is set out in RFC 4514 (which replaces RFC 2253), and it is not really fully parseable with a regex. OpenLDAP contains some library functions which will parse and validate, for what it's worth. However, if you need a quick-and-dirty regex, you can use the following Posix ERE: `([^\,]|\\.)*` (In Perl, Python, or other languages with similar regex extensions, use `(?:[^\,]|\\.)*` to avoid the needless capture.)

This means "match any sequence of characters other than `,` and `\`, possibly also including pairs of `\` and any single character". This is a superset of the actual LDAP specification, which does not allow `\` to be followed by anything other than hex digits or one of a handful of special characters, so it will accept a number of invalid DN components, but it should accept all valid ones and, I believe, will never swallow a comma which separates DN components.

Here's a simple test, in bash, using grep:

```
$ echo 'CN=lastName\, firstName,OU=Users - XYZ,OU=Users-Test Place,OU=UsersAll,DC=Dom1,DC=Dom2' |
> grep -oE '([^\,]|\\.)*'
CN=lastName\, firstName
OU=Users - XYZ
OU=Users-Test Place
OU=UsersAll
DC=Dom1
DC=Dom2
```